# MOM vs SOA? the difference?

Tags: soa, mom

they have many common features. but how the difference?

MOM allow asynchronous while SOA does not, this is the only difference?

Answer (score 22):

SOA, Service Oriented Architecture, is an architecture that defines how to structure access to business information between different applications. In a nutshell, usually, one application needs something done with a piece of information (may it be an orderfile or anything else) that application has a need. Another application may be able to do the corresponding processing of that piece of information, hence it has a capability. The first application then Consumes the Service of the second application, which Provides the Service (no matter the underlying technology, which can be anything such as JMS, HTTP/SOAP, HTTP/REST, EMail, FTP, etc.). To make this work, a Contract between the first application and the Service has to be defined which clears such things out as Message Format (XSD or similar), Protocol (HTTP/SOAP? JMS?) etc.

MOM, Message Oriented Middleware, on the other hand is just a family of software/middleware platforms. They are actual implementations, and not a high-level concept like SOA. They can be used to implement a SOA architecture, an Event Driven architecture or other architectures. Usually, MOM enriches a set of applications with asynchronous messaging where a MOM server stores and forwards the messages. Often things such as transactions, guranteed delivery, fail-over, loose coupling and load balancing are built into MOM implementations. Examples of MOM are [IBM WebSphere MQ](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/), Apache [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), JBoss [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq), etc.

Answer (score 8):

Message oriented middleware (MOM) is a type of technology where as SOA is a type of architecture.  Even though a lot of people think about web-service when they talk about SOA, you can use MOM to implement it as well (in fact in many cases that's the better option)